# Possible names for a process Linux?

Tags: linux

I am trying to write a script in which I read from `/proc/.../stat`. One of the values in the space separated list is the name of the process, which does not interest me for the time being. I would like to read some other value after it. My idea was to move forward a certain number of values using spaces as the separator. A potential problem with this though is that I could have `/proc/.../stat` containing something like `1234 (asdf asdf) S ...`. The space in the process name would cause the program to read `asdf)` instead of `S` as intended.

So my question is can the process name have spaces in it? If so how could I differentiate between the values in `/proc/.../stat`?

Comment: Language? Generally, use quotes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm using C/C++, but i don't think it would make a difference of what is in /proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, personally, hate the way this file is laid out for precisely the reason you stated. With that said, it is possible to parse it uniquely no matter what the process name is. This is important, because not only the process name may contain spaces, it may *also contain the close bracket character*.

The method I suggest is to manually parse out the process name, and use space delimiting for everything else.

The process name should be defined as starting at the first open-bracket character on the line and ending at the **last** close bracket on the line. Since the other fields on the line don't have user-controlled format, this should reliably single the process name out, no matter what weird ways the proces is named.